# What is the meaning of masu-stem + proposition

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

Example sentence:

> オオカミのことばに**従い**、　森に行った。

What is the meaning of this construction? Does it have a special meaning?

Comment: At the risk of (inadvertently) answering the question in a comment...if you mean "従い," I just moused over it with Rikaikun and it gave the definition as an expression meaning "in accordance with; subordinate to."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bare ます-stem can be used to join sentences together, much like the て-form.  Another valid way to render this sentence would be as follows:

> オオカミのことばに従って、森に行った。

In both cases it translates to "In accordance with the wolf's words, [I] went to the woods."

Comment: Is there a different nuance between using the て-form or the ます-stem?

Comment: @olorin Yes, ます-stem (eg ～にしたがい、/～により、/～へ行き、/～と聞き、etc) sounds more literary and formal than て-form (eg ～にしたがって、/～によって、/～へ行って、/～と聞いて、etc).