# Expressing concurrency

Tags: grammar

> 人口が増える　[　に伴い／とともに　]　周辺もにぎやかになってきた。
>   Jinkou ga fueru (ni tomonai/to tomo ni) shuuhen mo nigiyaka ni natte kita

Both the options seem grammatically correct. What's the difference then? Or do I understand it wrong?

Comment: Is this homework?  What does your book say about the choices?

Comment: I have not found any reference which explains the apt choice in this(and similar cases of concurrency).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, they are nearly identical and interchangeable.  One of my grammar books has the exact same wording for both structures.

> *～すると、それと一緒に*
>   動詞の辞書形／名詞　＋　{に伴って・とともに}

参照: [Proportion and Rate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2528/78)

Comment: In the question, it's ～に伴い though, which I think is quite different from ～に伴って since the former would be a coordinate clause (<- not sure if it's the right term)

Comment: @3to5businessdays: [What is the meaning of masu-stem + proposition](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17930/78)

Comment: Fair enough, it appears I have a mistaken view of 中止形

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that に伴い feels slightly more formal than に伴って or とともに (at least to me) exactly because it is using the 中止形.