# Usage and meaning of 仲ばし

Tags: usage, conjugations, renyōkei

While reading I came across a strange usage which none of my dictionaries could decipher.

> 腰を**仲ばし**、両手を大きく振りながら、てくてく歩く。

While googling I found the sentence 手を前方に進め上体を倒しながら**仲ばします** accompanied by a picture of someone doing stretching exercises.

From what I know ば is a particle used for conditions but I don't know how 仲 comes into the picture.

Comment: It is a conjugation of the verb 伸【の】ばす. See for example [this question for the conjugation.](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17930/what-is-the-meaning-of-masu-stem-proposition) Does the [dictionary entry for this verb help?](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/59135/m0u/伸ばす/) Or are you uncertain about the precise meaning of the phrase 腰を伸ばす?

Comment: @blutorange You are missing the incorrectness of the kanji.  It is not about conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「腰を**仲**ばし」 makes no sense I am afraid.  Are you sure it was not

「腰を**伸**ばし」?

「[腰]{こし}を[伸]{の}ばす」 means "to straighten oneself".

The sentence you found on google is incorrect as well.  It should be 「伸ばします」 at the end.

Comment: Oh wow I feel bloody stupid now. Just goes to show that I need to brush up more on my reading skills a hundredfold.